# CSS Image Navigation Bar - Want Javascript Click to retain hover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

So I have made a Navigation bar using Images, and at the moment, when I hover over them the image changes to have a red bar along the top. I would like to retain this red bar when a user clicks so they can see what page they are currently on. I know I need Javascript for this, and the click function, and perhaps to give it an active class but I don't know how to do the rest. e.g. the CSS for the .active state aswell, as each li on the bar is a different size.. Is this possible?!

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav-example">
    <li id="nav-example-01"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id="nav-example-02"><a href="#">Solar PV Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="nav-example-03"><a href="#">Ancillary</a></li>
    <li id="nav-example-04"><a href="#">Electrical Services</a></li>
    <li id="nav-example-05"><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li id="nav-example-06"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="nav-example-07"><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li id="nav-example-08"><a href="#">Referral Scheme</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-example {
    background:url("nav2.jpg") no-repeat;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 47px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav-example li, #nav-example a {
    height: 47px;
    display: block;
}

#nav-example li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#nav-example-01 { width: 70.5px; }
#nav-example-02 { width: 178.5px; }
#nav-example-03 { width: 100.5px; }
#nav-example-04 { width: 185.5px; }
#nav-example-05 { width: 135px; }
#nav-example-06 { width: 92px; }
#nav-example-07 { width: 67.5px; }
#nav-example-08 { width: 170.5px; }

#nav-example-01 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") 0px -47px no-repeat; }
#nav-example-02 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") -70.5px -47px no-repeat; }
#nav-example-03 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") -248.5px -47px no-repeat; }
#nav-example-04 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") -349px -47px no-repeat; }
#nav-example-05 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") -534.5px -47px no-repeat; }
#nav-example-06 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") -669.5px -47px no-repeat; }
#nav-example-07 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") -761.5px -47px no-repeat; }
#nav-example-08 a:hover { background:url("nav2.jpg") -829px -47px no-repeat; }
```

JAVASCRIPT?:

```
$("#nav-example a").on('click', function () {
            $("#nav-example a").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is your `:hover` event working?

Comment: Have a demo that we can play with? Using something like PlaceKitten or Lorem Pizza you can have images as well. Based on looking at it it seemd the active class is not being removed correctly? What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: My :hover event was working and I fixed it now! :D Took me a few hours but I figured it out. Always feels good when you finally crack the code :P Thank you for replying though :)